# ansible write variable to local file

Tags: ansible

I have the following ansible playbook that writes the content of the variable "hello" as a message (I got this code from an example online). I tried modifying it so it would write this to a local file however I got an error. The modified code and error message are below:

original code (successful):

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
    hello: world
  tasks:
  - name: Ansible Basic Variable Example
    debug:
      msg: "{{ hello }}"
```

modified code (unsuccessful):

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
    hello: world
  tasks:
  - name: Ansible Basic Variable Example
  - local_action: copy content={{hello}} dest=~/ansible_logfile
    debug:
      msg: "{{ hello }}"
```

error message:

```
ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to have been in '/space/mathewLewis/towerCodeDeploy/playBooks/test.yml': line 5, column 5, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  tasks:
      - name: Ansible Basic Variable Example
    ^ here
```

I would like to know how to write a variable to a file correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple syntax error.
A Task is an entry in the list of tasks, which in YAML is designated by a `-` (dash).
Task names are optional in Ansible.
Both [`copy`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html) and [`debug`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html) are modules, which are supposed to be a task's "action".
What the error message is telling you is that the task with `name: Ansible Basic Variable Example` does not have an action, which is because your `local_action` is a separate task, indicated by a `-`.

Fixing your example with appropriate names for the tasks:

```
  - name: Write variable to file
    local_action: copy content="{{hello}}" dest=~/ansible_logfile

  - name: Output the variable
    debug:
      msg: "{{ hello }}"
```

Comment: There is one more problem with quoting the expansion of **content="{{ hello }}"**.

Answer (score 0):

Thomas Hirsh's answer is correct.  However, I found this representation less confusing (I'm a newbie to ansible):

```
- name: "Controller"
  hosts: "controller.jeff.ddns.net"
  tasks:
    - name: "Register a variable to be shared with the clients"
      set_fact: shared_fact="Brother"

- name: "Client"
  hosts: "client.jeff.ddns.net"
  tasks:
    - name: "writing to hostvars.json"
      local_action: copy content="{{hostvars | to_json(indent=4) }}" dest="hostvars.json"
```

This example has two plays.  The controller play only sets a variable.  The client is what actually writes to the file.  In this case, hostvars has a complicated structure, so I used the `to_json(indent=4)` filter to convert to a good `.json` file, suitable for use with `jq` .